# Error when build Android App: SupportedAbis should not be null

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have the following error when running the Android app:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processStagingDebugManifest'. supportedAbis should not be null when no splits are computed
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find out any solution for this. I am facing same issue.